# Reasoning about the Heilbronn-Rohrbach Inequality and natural density

Tags: number-theory, inequality, analytic-number-theory

Let $A$ be a set of natural numbers.

Let $F(x,A)$ denote the number of natural numbers $n \le x$ divisible by no elements of $A$.

The [Heilbronn-Rohrback Inequality](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022314X80900323) says:

$$\Delta(A)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{F(x,A)}{x} \ge \prod_{a\in A}(1-1/a) $$

Does this tell us anything about the value of $F(x,A)$?  Can this be used to establish a lower bound for $F(x,A)$?

I've read the Wikipedia article on [natural density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density) and if this relationship exists, I'm not clear why it is not called out.  On the other hand, if it doesn't have this relationship, I am unclear how the density inequality provides insights into the properties of natural numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L$ be the least common multiple of $A$. An integer $n$ is divisible by no elements in $A$ iff $n+L$ is divisible by no elements in $A$. This $L$-periodicity will give us some bounds: $$(x-L)\Delta(A)\leq F(x,A)\leq (x+L)\Delta(A)$$
(You'll want to double-check that; I haven't proved it, but it looks right.) Then applying the Heilbronn-Rohrback Inequality gives us this lower bound:
$$F(x,A)\geq (x-L)\prod_{a\in A}(1-1/a)$$